# How to use pip3 install packages for Python 3.5 in ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Ubuntu 14.14 server itself has installed Python 3.4 in default, however, I need to use Python 3.5 for certain packages. So I install it by myself.

The problem is that every time I try to install packages by running "pip3 install xxx". It always installs under Python 3.4 rather than 3.5.

Please show me some lights on how to use Python 3.5 properly on Ubuntu. Many thanks for any good suggestions!

Comment: `which pip3` returns what? Have you tried running `python3`? How did you install python if not apt-get?

Comment: Try to type pip3 (no space after pip3) and press tab - chances are you have more than one pip3 and pip3 is a symbolic link. Alternatively, try creating a virtualenv

Comment: you should have `pip3.5` and `pip3.4` - the same `python3.5` and `python3.4`

Comment: You should also specify the version of python you're working with in conjunction with pip

Comment: I've got pip3 and pip3.4 and I think they are the same. Not sure how to install pip3.5. As for what I google, it only shows how to install pip3.

Comment: pip3 -V  shows "pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install it to the right version of python, type:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install [package]
```

Now this is assuming the name of Python 3.5 is `python3`.
If this is not the case,

1. Create an alias of Python 3.5 to some `name`
2. Replace python3 in the snippent above with that `name`.
3. Execute the command.